# how do I know if the BIOS or the OS is throttling my CPU? (Linux)

Tags: linux, cpu, bios, throttling, cpu-throttling

I'm using Ubuntu Linux 18.04.
I've been sold a secondhand Dell Precision M6700 Laptop with an underpowered power adaptor.

Apparently, the BIOS can recognize this condition, and I read somewhere that it will apply an extreme throttle to the CPU.

How can I check if the throttle is on or not?

Comment: Other than checking the CPU speed?

Answer (score 5):

To find the current CPU speed on all cores:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu MHz"
```

You can also check `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy{N}/scaling_max_freq` and see if it is consistent with your CPU model. Other files in the same directories may be of interest (`energy_performance_preference`)

Comment: You may waht to use watch in addtion, to get live data: ```watch 'cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu MHz"'```